# Displaying 2nd level of product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can't seem to figure out the way of showing 2nd level of the woocommerce product categories in dropdown.

So far i have this

```
function lvl_1()
    {  
        $args = array(
            'show_option_all'    => ' ',
            'name'         => 'Marka',
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'show_count'   => 0,
            'pad_counts'   => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'hide_empty'   => 0,
            'parent'       => 0,
        );
        $lvl_1_categories = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );  

    }
    function lvl_2()
    {
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',           
            'parent'       => 0,
        );
        $lvl_1_categories = get_categories( $args );  
        $args2 = array(
            'show_option_all'    => ' ',
            'name'         => 'Modelis',
            'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
            'orderby'      => 'name',
            'show_count'   => 0,
            'pad_counts'   => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'hide_empty'   => 0,  
            // Somewhere here i should get a value of first level elements to dispaly their childer, thats what i think.
            );
        $lvl_2_categories = wp_dropdown_categories( $args2 );  
    }
```

lvl_1 function works fine, it shows top level categories, but is there a way to display 2nd level categories with this `wp_dropdown_categories()` function?

Answer (score 0):

place the following code and get list of all category.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
                'type'        => 'post',
                'child_of'    => 0,
                'orderby'     => 'id',
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'  => 0,
                'hierarchical'=> 0,           
                'taxonomy'    => 'category',
                'parent' => 0                                              
            ) );

$top_level_ids = [];
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if( ! $category->parent ) {
        $top_level_ids[] = $category->term_id;
    }
}
//print_r($top_level_ids);die;
$categories = get_categories( array(
                'type'        => 'post',
                'child_of'    => 0,
                'orderby'     => 'id',
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'  => 0,
                'hierarchical'=> 0,           
                'taxonomy'    => 'category',
            ) );

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    // Only output if the parent_id is a TOP level id
    if( in_array( $category->parent, $top_level_ids )) {
        echo $category->term_id . ', ' . $category->slug . ', ' . $category->name . '<br />';
    }
} die;
```

Comment: I only need the 2nd level categories, not all of them.

Comment: @Rhercb plz check above edited code. It will only get your 2nd level sub category.